# Como transformar coluna em linha no dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Tenho dois dataframes e gostaria de transformar os dados das duas colunas do 2º df em linhas para serem adicionadas em sequencia dos dados do 1º df. Para exemplificar crie os dois df e o resultado final.

```
df1 = data.frame(c("MG","SP","RJ","ES","PA"),c("PA","ES","MG","SP","RJ"))

colnames(df1) = c("Nome", "Estado")

df2 = data.frame(c("PA","ES","MG","SP","RJ"),c("MG","SP","RJ","ES","PA"))

colnames(df2) = c("Estado", "Nome")
```

O resultado transformaria o df em 10 observações com 2 colunas:

```
df3 = data.frame(c("MG","SP","RJ","ES","PA","PA","ES","MG","SP","RJ"),c("PA","ES","MG","SP","RJ","MG","SP","RJ","ES","PA"))

colnames(df3) = c("Nome", "Estado")
```

Comment: `rbind.data.frame(df1, df2)`?

Answer (score 2):

Para unir linhas de [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame)s diferentes você pode usar o `rbind` do pacote `base` ou o `bind_row` do [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

Assim teríamos:

```
library(tidyverse)

df4 <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
df5 <- rbind(df1, df2)
identical(df4, df5)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Note contudo que a resposta obtida não é igual a que você criou no `df3`.

```
identical(df3, df4)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Isso ocorre porque ambas as funções entendem que as observações de variáveis com o mesmo nome devem ser unidas sob essa variável e `df1`e `df2` tem os nomes das colunas invertidos.

Para produzir o resultado de df3 basta alterar os nomes de df2.

```
df5 <- bind_rows(df1, set_names(df2, c("Nome", "Estado")))
identical(df3, df5)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função rbind

```
df1 = data.frame(c("MG","SP","RJ","ES","PA"),c("PA","ES","MG","SP","RJ"))

colnames(df1) = c("Nome", "Estado")

df2 = data.frame(c("PA","ES","MG","SP","RJ"),c("MG","SP","RJ","ES","PA"))

colnames(df2) = c("Estado", "Nome")


df3<- rbind(df1, df2)
df3
```